# SQL Server Mgt Studio Query Editor window tabs aren't descriptive

Tags: sql-server-2005, configure, ssms

In SQL Server Mgt Studio 2005, when I open the Object Explorer to script an object to a new Query Editor window, the tab for that new script window is titled something like 'MyServerName.MyDatabaseName - sqlquery37.sql'

Not very descriptive. So when I get a bunch of windows open at the same time, I have no idea which one is which.

The 'Active Files' dropdown is useless because of this.

Is there a way to configure Mgt. Studio so that the Query Editor Window tab title more accurately reflects the object that I'm working on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something that the SQL team is aware of (see [this connect item](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=276832)) but there is no firm deadline on when it will be addressed. Saving your file as Ken G suggested is the only work around at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Not [easily] without actually saving the script window to a file - then you get

```
MyServerName.MyDatabaseName - MyFileName.sql
```

as the title.

You might be able to change this with a plugin/add-on, but not without writing code.

Answer (score 0):

I recently created [this suggestion](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/575463/sql-server-management-studio-ui-tabs-are-a-pain-to-use#) in which I offer an alternative UI for the tabs:

[(image) http://img190.imageshack.us/img190/7130/exampletabs2.png](http://img190.imageshack.us/img190/7130/exampletabs2.png)

If enough people upvote it, perhaps they will take it seriously!